Sending XTZ to Etherlink wallet
I just noticed that the Etherlink mainnet explorer is live.
I connected a new Metamask wallet via the explorer web UI and would like to test sending some XTZ from Tezos mainnet to this new wallet.
I saw a video that explains the high-level process on how Tezos -> Etherlink XTZ flows happen, but what are the concrete steps to do this in practice?

There is a bridge setup, where you connect a Tezos wallet and an Etherlink wallet (or supply a destination address) and it will create the necessary transactions to perform the trasnfer
https://bridge.etherlink.com/

With CLI on Etherlink mainnet:
octez-client --endpoint <RPC URL> transfer 5 from <L1 ADDRESS> to \ 
 KT1Wj8SUGmnEPFqyahHAcjcNQwe6YGhEXJb5 --entrypoint deposit \
 --arg 'Pair "sr1Ghq66tYK9y3r8CC1Tf8i8m5nxh8nTvZEf" <L2 ADDRESS starting with 0x>' \
 --burn-cap 1


From what I know:

Go to the EVM Bridge dapp
Connect your Tezos wallet holding the XTZ you want to transfer
Enter the amount of XTZ you want to transfer to Etherlink
Enter the Etherlink address of your Metamask wallet where you want to receive the bridged XTZ
Review and confirm the transaction in your Tezos wallet
Wait for the transaction to be processed on the Tezos blockchain
Your bridged XTZ will show up in your Metamask wallet connected to the Etherlink mainnet explorer.

